# SharePoint Audit Log Reports

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, auditing

My requirement is to have a report with the users rights for the past 5 years of data. It should have which user have the access rights to which content on a time in the past.

Is this possible using Out Of Box features of SharePoint 2010? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Abraham

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late answer...

For your first question, if Audit feature configured in your sharepoint application, you can able to get the reports.

For second question regarding the OOB aduit feature
Please check the below post, it will help you out

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/431342/Auditing-A-Built-in-Feature-of-SharePoint

Thanks,

Somasekhar Akiri.